# Class loading via reflection using a single class loader

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, reflection, classloader

I have a webapp project, which I am running through tomcat. The webapp project has a dependency of a core project. (The core project jar is present in WEB-INF/lib folder).

I have another sample project which has same core project dependency. I need to load a class and invoke a particular method present in the sample project jar via reflection.

I need to load core project's classes that are being used in the sample project as well as web app project via common class loader.

The problem is :- I am unable to load core project classes and sample project classes in a common class loader.

I have tried a lot from past two days like loading up classes using a custom class loader and system class loader, but I always end up getting either `NoSuchMethodException` or `ClassCastException` or `ClassNotFoundException`.

How should I handle this situation of having a common class loader?

> Class which I need to load and invoke a method (Sample Project)

```
public class ObjectiveFunction implements ScriptInterface{//ScriptInterface is a interface present in core project

@Override
public void execute(Map<Integer, CustomObject> map, IModel inputModel, List<AbstractNode> nodes) {
    for (Node node : nodes){// this line throws ClassCastException
 // IModel is an interface in core project
// AbstractNode (abstract class), CustomObject and Node are present in core project. Different nodes extends AbstractNode
    // Some logic
}
```

> Class loading code present in core project which is invoked by webapp
>   project

```
URLClassLoader classLoader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(classLoader, url);

Class<?> classToLoad = classLoader.loadClass(className);
Method executeMethod = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("execute", Map.class, IModel.class, List.class);

Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance();
executeMethod .invoke(instance, value1, value2, value3); // This line throws NoSuchMethodException
```

Comment: why don't you move the core project jar into `tomcat/lib` (the Common CL)?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I tried that but it still failed saying `NoSuchMethodException`.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: The code that throws a `NoSuchMethodException`, because it probably means that your code is not correct

Comment: @NicolasFilotto One more thing, when I use `getDeclaredMethods()` and loop over the `Method[]` array, then in the `execute` method it will throw `ClassCastException` (I have mentioned the line in the above code).

Comment: Show value1, value2 and value3 and make sure that the jar that contains the class `IModel` is in one single place not in both `WEB-INF/lib` directories, ideally it should be in `tomcat/lib` only

Comment: the idea is that 2 exact same classes but loaded from 2 different CL are 2 different Class instances at the end

Comment: @NicolasFilotto value1 is a `HashMap<Integer CustomObject>`, value2 is an instance which implements an `IModel` and value3 is `ArrayList<AbstractNode>` and one more thing when I moved core project jar to tomcat/lib folder I got exception of `ClassNotFoundException` for third party lib which core project is dependent but I did when the jar was present in both places. I will to run keeping that in one place.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I tried with keeping core jar only in tomcat/lib folder but no luck. log is `[Loaded com.example.core.IModel from file:/Apache_softwares/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/lib/example-core-jar-with-dependencies.jar]`
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sample.ObjectiveFunction.execute(java.util.Map, com.example.core.IModel, java.util.List)`. Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe you have several classes ObjectiveFunction in tomcat/lib?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto You mean to say same class name may exists in other jars which are present in tomcat/lib, I will try giving different name to that class and let you know.

Comment: Unless I can get the files to reproduce, I can hardly help you, sorry

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Changed the name of the class to ObjFunction still the same error.
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sample.ObjectiveFunction.execute(java.util.Map, com.example.core.IModel, java.util.List)`
Before this it is loading the class
`[Loaded com.example.core.IModel from file:/Apache_softwares/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/lib/example-core‌​-jar-with-dependenci‌​es.jar`
`[Loaded com.sample.ObjFunction from file:/home/user/Sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]`.
Should I add Sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to WEB-INF/lib/? Will it make any change?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Yeah i can understand, let me explain you the flow.
1) Webapp will call a method in core project (As webapp as core dependency).
2) Method in core project should invoke a method of class which is in sample project via reflection but this sample project also has core project dependency.
Any links or article to above situation is also fine. I would have given you files but those are slightly big projects.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I have invoked a method of `org.json` library via reflection without any problems with the same code from my web app and I have a junit test case which is working fine in core project. I think it is due to the double dependency.

Comment: If I were you I would try to reproduce with as less jars and classes as possible, following the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) principle

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I already started doing that, I will let you know once I am done and sorry for too many comments.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I have solved this issue. Thank You for your help.